# gtag call from HTML OnClick does not reach GA

Tags: html, google-analytics, gtag.js

Fumbled myself through realizing I am not using the old analytics.js but the gatg.js. 
The call below is not fired, so against the [Google documentation for ga to gtag Migration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration#track_events) it does not work that way:

```
<a href="https://example.com" 
    onclick="gtag('event', {
        'event_category': 'Downloads', 
        'event_action': 'download', 
        'event_label': 'softwarename', 
        'value': '1'});">
Download</a>
```

Any suggestion on how the gtag call has to be formatted, to get it workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stumbling over the [gtag.js documentaion](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#custom-events-and-parameters), I found another syntax got to be used and that indeed the conversion:

```
eventAction => event_action
```

Does not work as suggested as in the migration documentation lnked in the question.
The workable call drags the action parameter to the front like:

```
<a href="https://example.com" 
onclick="gtag('event', 'download', {
    'event_category': 'Downloads',  
    'event_label': 'softwarename', 
    'value': '1'});">Download</a>
```